# Delphi- How to get my full domain name

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

In my program I am trying to retrieve the domain name of the current machine.
i found some code that people wrote in forums but they all seem to work partially.

what i mean is that my domain name is something like 'mydomain.mydomain11.com'
and when trying to retrieve the domain name i always get only 'mydomain' instead of 'mydomain.mydomain11'

I also tried usng the 'GetEnvironmentVariable' function which returns the same thing.

If possible, i would like to know how can i retrieve the full path.

my final goal is to query active directory using LDAP protocol, so it will really help to know how can chunk the domain path to something like :

```
CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=mydomain11,DC=com
```

but getting my full domain name will do for now..

Comment: ok thanks, now i have a string containing the full domain name. is there a way of chunking it the way i used above so i can use it for LDAP qwery?

Comment: If you just want to connect to LDAP it's not required to know the domain name or dn, you can just connect to `LDAP://RootDSE`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677945(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I will want to search for a user/group on this domain later on...

Comment: Yes that's what you can use RootDSE for, last link in the RootDSE documentation gives you an example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676736(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks Remko, the example added made it clear to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [GetComputerNameEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724301(v=vs.85).aspx) function with the `ComputerNamePhysicalDnsDomain` parameter:

The name of the DNS domain assigned to the local computer. If the local computer is a node in a cluster, lpBuffer receives the DNS domain name of the local computer, not the name of the cluster virtual server.`

If your goal is to connect to LDAP to search objects in the directory the usual approach is to connect to RootDSE. Here is an [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676736(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: When the question is listed Delphi Object Pascal, why are all the answers & links reaching out to Microsoft?

Comment: @JosephPoirier  Delphi produces executables that run on the Microsoft Windows operating system (amongst others). Sometimes we need to write code that works directly with the operating system API.

Comment: Windows API's are required to read the DNS domain name which the computer is joined to.

Comment: See this answer for a delphi implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60754717/1855801

Answer (score 0):

ref  [What's the best method for getting the local computer name in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156544/whats-the-best-method-for-getting-the-local-computer-name-in-delphi)

ref  http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=29823
     under LorAn, pronounced Lorne - great framework for fetch

rolled in Delphi variable MAXCHAR for buffer size, should be the largest size that can be returned in shortest timeframe

```
function getDomain: string;
var
  vlDomainName : array[0..MAXCHAR] of char;
  vlSize : ^DWORD;
begin
  New(vlSize);
  vlSize^ := MAXCHAR;
  ExpandEnvironmentStrings(PChar('%USERDOMAIN%'), vlDomainName, vlSize^);
  Dispose(vlSize);
  Result := vlDomainName;
end;
```

To get DNSServer.DOMAIN.DOMAIN..

use ADSI library ADSystemInfo GetAnyDCName() function & split on the decimal [.]

Comment: OP was specifically asking how to get the domain name that the computer is joined to rather than the domain of the logged on user (which can be different in an AD forest or when using trusted domains). Also the `%USERDOMAIN%` variable returns the Netbios domain name (e.g. mydomain rather than mydomain.mydomain11.com). Lastly, why read an environment variable instead of using a proper API that was designed for the purpose?

Comment: ADSI function for DomainName was returning computername instead of DomainName. Obviously Microsoft created shortcut variables for a reason

Comment: Also, for developing software, I see no reason to run through AD groups that are outside of the user's current login for access. Can you provide a scenario where that would be a requirement?

Comment: ps. Remko. I didn't downvote your answer, I just didn't understand how it was considered complete. It is no more complete than mine is, per the question.